# Solution for the AX=XB matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Is there an analytical solution for the $AX=XB$ equation? $A,B,X \in SO(3)$, so $A,B$ and $X$ are all $3\times 3$ rotational matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is given and what is the solution you are seeking? Assuming the two rotations $A,B$ are given  and you want to find a rotation $X$ s.t. $AX=XB$ this problem has not always a solution $X\,.$ Just take $B$ as the identity matrix, and $A$ any rotation that is not the identity matrix.